# spreadsheet like asp.net and dynamic view

Tags: asp.net, database, spreadsheet

I want to create an application that users can select fields from database table and create a spreadsheet by those data. Is any control or sample to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the schema of table varies from database to database.
No matter which database you use, it would be easy to get the list of columns and let the user select which columns to show.

To create a speardsheet you should look at these controls [ASP.NET Real World Controls](http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/)

These custom controls enable you to create excel like grids in asp.net. It is open source allowing you to extend them as may be needed by your project.